# How to make Spring Tool Suite like a multi-maven-module project?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot project with multiple Maven modules. I've used the tutorial at  https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/  .

This site recommends a directory tree like this:

```
parent
    application
        src, and other subdirectories
        pom.xml
    library
        src, and other subdirectories
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

I developed this project using Visual Source Code.

Wanting to see the project in another light, I tried to import the project directories into Spring Tool Suite.  I'm using a recent one, where you apply the STS plugin to an up-to-date Eclipse installation.

Well, STS doesn't really like this project.

- The (File, Open projects from file system) sees the project, but the Finish button doesn't actually do anything.
- The (File, Import, General, Existing Projects into Workspace) imports a project, but as a Maven project (no "J" icon).  When I try the (Run, Run Configurations) it won't see my project.

How can such a project be made friendly to Spring Tool Suite?

Thanks,

Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

To make multi maven projects what you can do is, simply download two separate maven projects from start.spring.io and then extract them and move both folders to one parent folder and try grabbing the parent folder to Intellij, so it automatically downloads the dependencies and other requirement for the project in which we have two maven projects in one single entity

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can be a bit confusing with several different Wizards to import projects. Ironically the wizards are supposed to make importing projects easy, and in a sense they do... but... unfortunately picking the right wizard itself can be a bit challenging / confusing. Which wizard you use depends on the type of project.

Since your projects are maven projects, the best wizard to use would be the one for maven projects. You can find it at "File >> Import >> Existing Maven Projects".

So give that a try, point it at the 'parent' folder of your project and you should be presented with a relatively intuitive UI to import all 3 projects and configure them for use in Eclipse.